# How can I run docker image in Azure app service with privileged option?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, deployment, web-applications

I'm trying to deploy docker image in Azure web app with privileged option.
But I don't know how to customize docker run command in Azure web apps.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly customize the DOCKER RUN command that App Service generates. Also, there's no way to run a privileged container in App Service.